# SQL : Update ID; According to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table below.

[image]

I like to *Update* `ID` according to date and then by User.

#### For Example

[image]

#### Thanks

Comment: so I assume that the example given was the output right? how was the data looked like before the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9af3/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
  MYUser char(3),
  Date date,
  ID int
)

insert into YourTable(MYUser, Date) values
('U55', '2012-10-05'),
('U55', '2012-10-10'),
('U22', '2012-10-06'),
('U55', '2012-10-01'),
('U55', '2012-10-07'),
('U22', '2012-10-04'),
('U55', '2012-10-09'),
('U22', '2012-10-02'),
('U22', '2012-10-03'),
('U55', '2012-10-08')
```

**Query 1**:

```
update T 
set ID = rn
from
  (
    select ID,
           row_number() over(partition by MYUser order by Date) as rn
    from YourTable
  ) as T


select *
from YourTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9af3/1/0)**:

```
| MYUSER |       DATE | ID |
----------------------------
|    U55 | 2012-10-05 |  2 |
|    U55 | 2012-10-10 |  6 |
|    U22 | 2012-10-06 |  4 |
|    U55 | 2012-10-01 |  1 |
|    U55 | 2012-10-07 |  3 |
|    U22 | 2012-10-04 |  3 |
|    U55 | 2012-10-09 |  5 |
|    U22 | 2012-10-02 |  1 |
|    U22 | 2012-10-03 |  2 |
|    U55 | 2012-10-08 |  4 |
```

Comment: You win the "Mindreader of the Year" award for figuring out what they wanted.

Comment: Mikael - I think you are the first person to use the Markdown format option on SQL Fiddle!  Woohoo! It wasn't all for naught! lol cheers

Comment: @JakeFeasel I am honored to be the first :). I like and use your site quite a lot. You are doing a great job with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Common Table Expression` for this, and join it from the original table, example:

```
WITH newID
AS
(
  SELECT [User], [DATE],
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bb.[User]
                            ORDER BY DATE ASC) RN
  FROM table1 bb
)
UPDATE a
  SET a.ID = b.RN
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
      newID b ON a.[User] = b.[User] AND
              a.[Date] = b.[Date]
```

- [***SQL Fiddle Demo (records are slightly different)***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fab3/11)